# Can I use two different types of class in the same controller file?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I'm using the use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password; on the Password Validation rules and the use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password; for the password reset the application is displaying error then I put the two of them together.

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use App\Models\User;
    use Illuminate\Support\Str;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use App\Mail\PasswordResetMail;
    
    use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use function GuzzleHttp\Promise\all;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
    use Illuminate\Auth\Events\PasswordReset;
    use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
    
    class UserController extends Controller
    {
        // Show Register/Create Form
        public function create()
        {
            return view('users.register');
        }

    // Create New User
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $formFields = $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'min:3', 'max:255', Rule::unique('users', 'name')],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', Rule::unique('users', 'email')],
            'password' =>
            [
                'required', 'confirmed',
                Password::min(8)
                    ->max(255)
                    ->mixedCase()
                    ->letters()
                    ->numbers()
                    ->symbols()
                    ->uncompromised(),
            ],
        ]);
```

Here for the Password Reset

```
// Submit Forgot Password 
    public function forgotSubmit(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate(['email' => 'required|email']);

        $status = Password::sendResetLink(
            $request->only('email')
        );

        return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
            ? back()->with(['status' => __($status)])->with('reset', 'We have e-mailed your password reset link!')
            : back()->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
    }
```

Comment: You can't but you can use an alias for that case `use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password as ValidationPassword;` https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use two types of class in one controller, but you should use like below. This is known as an import statement with an alias.

```
    use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password as CustomPassword;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
```

After that you can use `CustomPassword` where `Rules\Password` should be used.